# Consider the differential equation $y'=ty(3-y), t\ge0$, determine the initial value $y(t_0)=y_0$ so that the solution to the IVP is certain to exist.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $y'=ty(3-y), t\ge0$, determine the initial value $y(t_0)=y_0$ so that a solution to the IVP is certain to exist. I’m wondering if there's a way to answer this without solving the differential equation?

Comment: Why you don't want to use differential equations?

Comment: @SarGe I thought there might exist another way so that we could get around with solving the equation?

Comment: I personally didn't find any other way to solve other than differential equation. Let's see what other users think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you can answer the question for local solution and that the task is asking for global solutions on $\Bbb R_+$.

The roots $y=0$ and $y=3$ on the right side are constant solutions. Any solution starting between these values stays bounded by them and thus exists for all $t\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one test which is as follows:

For the IVP $y'=f(t, y), y(t_0)=y_0$, the sufficient condition to have solutions is that $f(t, y) $ must be continuous in some rectangular domain containing $(t_0,y_0)$ and

for the solution **to be unique** the sufficient condition is that the partial derivative $\frac{\partial (ty(1-y)) }{\partial y} $ must be continuous in some rectangular domain containing $(t_0,y_0)$

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems somehow unclear and naive. It is not reasonable when asking to solve an ODE without using any ODE tool.

For any initial value $y(0)=y_0$, that differential equation has a (unique) solution that is not only locally but also globally defined. This can be deduced from some basic results in theory of ODEs.

Comment: using change of variable $s=t^2/2$, the equation is actually a [logistic one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Logistic_differential_equation)

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&=ty(3-y)\\
\dfrac{dy}{d(t^2/2)}=\dfrac{dy}{tdt}&=y(3-y)\\
\dfrac{dy}{ds}&=y(3-y)\\
y&=\dfrac{3}{1+C e^{-3s}}\\[5mm]
y&=\dfrac{3}{1+C e^{-3t^2/2}}.
\end{align*}

Other solutions are $y=0$ and $y=3$.

Hope this helps!